# How to respond to "I'm so old!"

Tags: management, behavior

I work for a Pharmacy at a hospital in Canada.

Today, I had a "1 on 1" with our new manager; basically an opportunity for her to get to know her staff.

Part way through, she asked me about what music I liked, and in response, she listed a few "classic rock" bands like Queen and Pink Floyd. I jokingly mentioned how that was the kind of music I grew up with since that's what my Dad listens to. To this she said, "I know, I'm so old!".

I had no idea how to respond to this. She isn't old by any means (I'd guess ~30), but I didn't know if it was appropriate to contradict her, as that might have been seen as sucking up to, or hitting on her.

I ended up just kind of smiling and laughing to myself while looking away (I'm kind of awkward).

What would have been an appropriate response?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What would have been an appropriate response?

Smiling and laughing is a perfectly appropriate response to what appears to have been a mild joke.

Saying "You're not old!" would have been fine as well.

This isn't a big deal, and certainly nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

You could either say:

> "[Age ain't nothing but a number.](https://youtu.be/rRwhm-B6yNI)"

Or

> "You're only as old as you feel."

...In order to remove the awkwardness from the conversation.